# Array is being ignored outside of my loops

Tags: java, arrays

I have a very problematic bit of code at the moment that is causing me a lot of stress. Essentially I'm trying to write a boardgame that asks players questions in a round format, switching from player 1 to player 2 and keeping their score/board position in an array. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this, but there is a more pressing issue at hand.

At the moment I'm baffled as to why my array created in a different method is being completely ignored outisde of the loops controlling a bunch of questions. I'm pretty sure I've passed the array method correctly to the `questions` method as I've put in a line of code within the loop to print out the array after every question and it is giving me back a board position (although there is a problem here, it is not updating cumulatively. That is, after the first question I'd be on position 3 but after the second question it would tell me to move forward 5 places to place 5, rather than to place 8). When I tell the code to print this *outside* of the loop, it just prints out 0, which is exactly what I don't want it to do.

```
public static void main (String[] param)
{ 
   numberPlayers();
   yourQuiz();
   int[] scoretrack = scorearray();
   int diceroll = dicethrow(6);
   questions(diceroll, scoretrack);
   System.exit(0);
}  


public static int[] scorearray()
{
   int scoreplayer1 = 0;
   int scoreplayer2 = 0;
   int[] scoretrack = {scoreplayer1, scoreplayer2};
   return  scoretrack;
}

/********************************************************************************************************
This method is where the questions are asked to the players. A dice is rolled to determine what question
is asked to the player and then, depending on if the answer is correct, another dice is rolled to see how
many squares the player advances. The square that the player is on is stored in score[0] for player 1 and score[1]
for player 2. This is where the main problem lies; score[0] doesn't store the board place cumulatively, 
i.e when the second question is asked the boardplace from the first question isn't stored
*********************************************************************************************************/

public static int questions(int diceroll, int[] score)
{
String playertwo;
int ans1 = 0;
String textinput;
int result;
String continueornot = input("Do you wish to continue?");
scorearray();

 while (!continueornot.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
 {

  if (diceroll == 1)
  { 

   while (ans1 != 19)
   {
      textinput = input("What's 9+10?");
      ans1 = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
      output("That's certainly an interesting answer"); 

    if (ans1 == 19)
    {
       output("FANTASTIC ANSWER, THAT'S CORRECT!");
       diceroll = dicethrow(diceroll);
       score[0] = score[0] + diceroll;
       output("Move forward " + diceroll + " squares. You are on square " + score[0]);
       System.out.println(score[0]); // this prints out the score here, but not cumulatively
       return yourQuiz();
    } // if they get the answer right

    else 
    {
       playertwo = input("Sorry, the answer was 19. Next player type yes to continue or no to exit");

        if (playertwo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            //return questions(diceroll, score);
        }

        else 
        {
           System.out.println(score[0]);
           System.exit(0);
        }
    } // if they get the answer wrong

   } // END while 1

  } // END if dice rolls 1

} // end while answer isn't no

   System.out.println(score[0]); // this doesn't actually print out what the boardplace is, it just prints 0 twice. Array is being ignored?

   return 500; // had to return a random number because it was giving me a 'return value missing' error
```

If there is anything unclear about what I am asking or what is written in the code please ask me and I will attempt to clarify. I am really desperate for help and I'd be eternally grateful if someone could just point out what I've messed up as I've been deliberating over this for a *very very* long time now. Thank you!

Comment: you could add some println step by step to observe your datas, check your algorithm and localize the problem(s)

Comment: Where are you calling `questions` and what array are you passing to it?

Comment: @Eran I'm not. At least I don't think I am. I am attempting to do the opposite; pass the array method to `questions`

Comment: @Overclock Your `questions` method has an array parameter (`score`). Where are you calling that method and what are you passing in place of that array parameter?

Comment: @Eran I've just had a look and I don't think I'm calling that method anywhere. I'm not sure if I've misunderstood you, but I am fairly new to this programming stuff, so I apologise if I sound really silly. Could you please elaborate a tiny bit?

Comment: @Overclock If you're not calling this method, it's not relevant to your question, so why did you post the code of that method in the first place?

Comment: @Eran I'm sorry, I thought it was relevant so I posted it because I thought it might help. Also, where I have `public static int questions(int diceroll, int[] score)` I am trying to pass a method to roll a dice written elsewhere (this works no problem) and the scorearray method to `questions`. I was told I could pass them under any name if I used that name within the method. I will update my code to show the main method too, as that might explain what I mean.